# Html photo gallery - remove space

Tags: html, css, image, gallery, responsive

I have a photo gallery in HTML / CSS and I have a space between 2 photos. I want the space to be like in photo (in left)

```css
.portfolio-img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img4.jpg" class="portfolio-img">

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Check Image]

Comment: it is not clear what you want - perhaps you mean something like https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53265432/edit) the snippet I made and add images from [lorempixel.com or similar](https://www.johanbostrom.se/blog/the-best-image-placeholder-services-on-the-web)

Comment: Have a look at https://codepen.io/jensimmons/pen/XdBxav

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.porfolio-img {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

`background-size: cover` will ensure that the source image covers the area of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving height in `%` please change it to `px`

```css
.portfolio-img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 300px; /* ---> give height it as you want */
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="images/img4.jpg" class="portfolio-img">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example in w3school website

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery

In summary you use display flex and divide the images into columns

This is the result for your case

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
  flex: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.portfolio-img {
  width:100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1089562/pexels-photo-1089562.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" class="portfolio-img filter development">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1037996/pexels-photo-1037996.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" class="portfolio-img filter marketing">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1037995/pexels-photo-1037995.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" class="portfolio-img filter development">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1037999/pexels-photo-1037999.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="portfolio-img filter design">
  </div>
</div>
```